# How can I insert into table using defined functon in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have functions `Fn1`, `Fn2`, `Fn3` and I have a table with fields `V1`, `V2`, and `V3`.

I am not able to do the following

```
INSERT INTO Table1(V1, V2, V3) VALUES (  
  SELECT "MyDB"."Fn1"() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1,  
  SELECT "MyDB"."Fn2"() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1, 
  SELECT "MyDB"."Fn3"() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
);
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: A character, token, or clause is invalid or missing.DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=.;Y1 ,select "MyDB".;WHERE, DRIVER=3.67.26

Error Code: -104
```

Comment: please help me ,, I need it urgent

Comment: any help please to let me got a solution

Comment: You likely have two problems - 1) It's probably trying to use the quoted function names as strings, so gets confused when it turns out to be a function. 2) You only need one `SELECT` and `FROM ...` statement (you _can_ do multiple sub-selects, but you have to wrap them individually in parenthesis - which you shouldn't need here).  Also, just checking, calling the function on its own works correctly, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of the INSERT statement in the manual: it is either `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..)` or `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. You are trying to use both.

Answer (score 0):

@mustaccio is right. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(V1, V2, V3) VALUES (
  ("MyDB"."Fn1"()),
  ("MyDB"."Fn2"()),
  ("MyDB"."Fn3"())
);
```

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/201d5/3/0) a somewhat simplified version of what you're trying to achieve.